# Domain rejoin as post imaging task

Tags: windows, powershell, deployment

**My Question:**

Edit: I'm specifically trying to do this programmatically through Powershell.

How can I check to see if a computer that is not currently joined to the domain (Freshly imaged) has an entry in the domain so that I can delete it prior to re-adding the computer to the domain? i.e. to ensure that as I image computers their old records are removed and only a single Computer object exists for each machine?

I know how to check if a computer is currently connected to a domain, and I know how to reconcile a trust relationship. Have I made a mistake in not using a script to pull the computer out of the domain as a pre-install task? I've already imaged a number of computers but I forgot some software and will be re-imaging again. So I'm hoping to get this implemented to remove all duplicate entries on the next go-around.

**Background:**

I've recently stepped into a network and domain that has less than 10% documentation available. It was one of those lovely systems that was more duct tape as it was built as-needed using whatever tutorials were available at the time.

In attempting to fix some of the more glaring issues, I've prepared a fresh Windows 10 image.

Now, all the computers are already in the domain, but because of the organizational issues and such, I'm using a powershell script to re-add them and put them into better defined OUs with names that make more sense. Previously devices were named after the individual that used them, but with so many staff changes that system is completely ineffective in tracking devices.

**Previous Search Attempts:**

I've tried searching for post image tasks for checking if a computer already exists before adding it to a domain, but the only results I've been able to get both through Google and Spiceworks are those that simply go over adding a computer or removing it from the domain, and the ones on repairing the trust relationship.

It may be simply that I'm not aware of the correct phrasing for the question, so if this has been answered before I would be ecstatic for someone to post the link for me.

**Thank you for reading!**

Comment: This is not a programming question, and is thus off-topic for Stack Overflow.  You may wish to consider asking on our sister site [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: I apologize, I should have included that I'm specifically attempting to do this with Powershell, and not via SCCM or anything of that nature. My employer uses a third party imaging solution that I'm trying to drop, but for this year's reimage I don't have time to build the new solution. I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution ended up being to simply add the computers to the domain and then after 90 days I ran a script to purge anything that hadn't reported into Active Directory. I did the same thing with accounts at a 180 day mark.

It meant I had ~10,000 extra items in Active Directory and had a negative impact on speed, but now that everything is properly tracked I won't have to repeat the process next year.

I made certain to back up all items using ldifde in the event that I accidentally deleted a machine that was only used at certain times of the year such as the ISTEP test caching machines. Being able to back them up made me much more willing to bypass reconciling the entries and to simply purge them.

Here is the script in case anyone comes across the same issue:

```
#I always set the location at the start of a script in case I forget at the end of a previous script.
Set-Location C:\

#ActiveDirectory is the only necessary module for this script.
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#While this is not 100% secure, I still feel it is better than leaving the credentials in plaintext within the code.
$keyfile = "\\[domain controller]\GPO Deployment Files\Scripts\AES.txt"
[byte[]] $key = ([byte array key])
$secure = Get-Content $keyfile | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key
$username = "[domain\admin]"
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
         -argumentlist $username, $secure

#Establishes the 90 day cutoff based off the current day.
$datecutoff = (Get-Date).AddDays(-90)

#As I wanted to go district-wide, I did not bother adding an OU based filter.
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {LastLogonDate -lt $datecutoff} -Properties * | Sort LastLogonDate | Select DistinguishedName,Name,LastLogonDate

#This is a test CSV - I ran all code up until this line so I could verify the list with a quick visual skim.
$computers | Add-Content -Path "\\[domain controller]\DeletedADItems\test.csv"

#Stepping through the list
Foreach ($computer in $computers) {

#I know there are likely elegant ways to do this, but using the -replace option was the simplest solution I could come up with at the time.
    $computername = $computer.Name -replace '@{name=',''
    $computername = $computername -replace '}',''
    $computerDN = $computer.DistinguishedName -replace '@{DistinguishedName=',''
    $computerDN = $computerDN -replace '}',''
<# I discovered that LDIFDE doesn't always play nicely with PS drives and such, or at least it failed to do so in my case.
So I back up the files to my local drive and then I copy them to the domain controller path that I used with the test.csv file. #>
    $exportFile = "C:\DeletedADItems\$computername.ldf"

#Prior to deletion, export the object to the export file location.
    ldifde -d "$computerDN" -f "$exportFile"

#Finally, remove the item and mark confirm false so you don't have to confirm hundreds of deletions.
    Remove-ADComputer -Identity "$computerDN" -Confirm:$False

}
```

It is mostly self-explanatory, but I added some basic comments just in case.